# how do I change discord bot presence in interactions,py

Tags: python, discord

I'm creating my discord bot with the interactions.py library and I've com across a problem.
I can't seem to set my bots presence:

```
import interactions
import os

from keep_alive import keep_alive

bot = interactions.Client(token=os.getenv('TOKEN'), command_prefix="!f")


@bot.event
async def on_start():
 activity = interactions.ClientPresence(
   name="zkus /mravenci",
   type=0,
 )
 await bot.change_presence(
   activity=interactions.PresenceActivityType.GAME(activity))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy.

```
await bot.change_presence(interactions.ClientPresence(activities=[interactions.PresenceActivity(name=f"{Your status here}", type=interactions.PresenceActivityType.WATCHING)]))
```

The **interactions.PresenceActivityType** sets the option, if the bot is play, watching, streaming and so on